# How to rewrite a sum of probabilities formula as multiplications?

Tags: probability, sum

I have an equation like that:

$p(r|s)= \frac{p(s,r)}{p(s)}=\frac{ \sum_{w,c} p(c,s,r,w)}{\sum_{w,c,r} p(c,s,r,w)} $

I am new to probability and I want to learn that how can I write sum formula as multiples of probabilities?

**PS 1:** I want something like:

$p(r|s)= \frac{  p(w,r|c,s)p(c,s)p(w,r|~c,s)p(~c,s)...}{ p(s|w,r,c)p(w,r,c)...} $

**PS 2:** Here is my Bayesian network:

[image]

**PS 3:** Because of conditionally independence I have that equations:

$p(w|r,s,c) = p(w|r,s)$

$p(r,s|c) = p(r|c)p(s|c)$

$p(r|s,c) = p(r|c)$

$p(s|r,c) = p(s|c)$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule for conditional probabilities is
$$P(A_1A_2\cdots A_n) = P(A_1)P(A_2\mid A_1)P(A_3\mid A_1A_2) \cdots
P(A_n\mid A_1A_2\cdots A_{n-1}).$$ In your notation (which might be
for joint probability mass functions or densities of random variables, this
becomes
$$p(a,b,c,\cdots, h) = p(a)p(b\mid a)p(c\mid a,b) \cdots p(h\mid a, b, c \cdots)$$
or, for those who march to the beat of a different drummer,
$$p(a,b,c,\cdots, h) = p(a\mid b,c,\cdots h)p(b\mid c, \cdots h)\cdots p(h)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the chain rule but confusing thing for me is that: it is sum of wc p(c,s,r,w) not just p(c,s,r,w) can you help for how to write it?

Comment: Mr. Sarwate, if you want to help me you can check my another related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234324/finding-probability-of-psw-at-bayesian-network-of-rain-problem